# Return next month name by passing a particular month name with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I need to get the next and previous months name by passing a month name to a function.

When I do this:

```
$date = Carbon::now(); // suppose Current month is May
$lastMonth =  $date->subMonth()->format('F'); // returns April
$nextMonth =  $date->addMonth()->format('F'); // returns June
```

The above code works fine. But I have a function where I need to pass the month name:

```
 $month = "Feburary"; // it can be any random month
 function getNextMonth($month)
    {
       //$date = Carbon::now();
       return $date->addMonth()->format('F'); // need the output to be March
    }
```

In this function how can I use the `$month` name to get the next month name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `createFromFormat`:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('F-d', "$month-1")->addMonth()->format('F');
```

The `-d`/`-1` is just to make sure it will always be the beginning of the month and not overflow to the next month depending on the current date.

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation (it's about the 10th block down from this link)

Comment: Aweome. +1 for the explanation

Comment: I am aready using `subMonthNoOverflow` and `addMonthNoOverflow`, will I need `-d`/`-1` also?

Comment: @Saurabh I believe so because those methods are for methods for modifying an instance where as the `-d`/`-1` bit is for the creation of the instance.

Comment: Final code for me `Carbon::createFromFormat('F-d', "$month-1")->addMonthNoOverflow()->format('F');` works like a charm. Added `NoOverflow` because I was having trouble with month which has 31 days (weird)

Comment: @Saurabh I believe so because those methods are for methods for modifying an instance where as the `-d`/`-1` bit is for the creation of the instance.